# Infinite TimerTask method call

Tags: java, java-me, timertask

maybe you could help to understand some things about TimerClass:

Assume i got a timer

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
```

And a data-fetching task

```
timer.shedule(new DataFetcher, 0, time);
```

Assume a short interval to execute the task plus an theoretical infinite running program, may it appear that, when the period is short enough or the execution of the task takes too long, i'll end up with lots of DataFetcher instances? 
If i change the sheduling

```
DataFetcher df = new DataFetcher();
timer.shedule(df, 0, time);
```

would this ensure that i'd always work with the same task instance? I tried to simulate that, to estimate the behaviour, but i'm kinda stuck.

Greetings

Please notice that im working on a mobile device using j2me. I know about timer alternatives in std java but i guess its not suitable for the microedition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both your versions are the same: you will have only one instance of `DataFetcher`, which is the proper way to do it.

Also, from the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule(java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long)):

> In fixed-delay execution, each execution is scheduled relative to the actual execution time of the previous execution. If an execution is delayed for any reason (such as garbage collection or other background activity), subsequent executions will be delayed as well.

Therefore the tasks will not accumulate, they are executed one after an other.

Comment: Thats exactly what i was searching for. Tyvm. Stupid me failing so hard on docu research :O